# Using PHP or JS to load the same template across all my pages, THEN update the loaded template with page specific info

Tags: javascript, php, html, jquery

I have a template file which contains some basic HTML markup. Using Javascript, this template file is loaded on every page. How do I make it so the template will remove "Demo Title" and replace it with "Contact Us" or "Information" based on the page its on? ...I know the solution requires some type of variable, but not sure how to achieve that.

---

For simplicity, I have 3 HTML pages.

- contact-us.html
- information.html
- title-image-description.html

---

I have created a template file called `title-image-description.html` which contains the HTML markup for a title area, image area, and description area.

**title-image-description.html**

```
<div class="title">Demo Title</div>
<div class="image">Demo Image</div>
<div class="description">Demo Description</div>
```

---

I have created `contact-us.html` and `information.html` which contains JavaScript AJAX which will load the `title-image-description.html` on these pages.

**contact-us.html & information.html**

```
<div id="title-image-description.html"></div>

<script>
$(function(){$("#title-image-description").load("title-image-description.html");});
</script>
```

---

**THE ISSUE:**
The page title, image, and description is not updated.

**Expected Result**

- `contact-us.html` shows the title "Contact Us", description "Welcome to Contact Us"
- `information.html` shows the title "Information", description "Welcome to Information"

**Actual Result**

- `contact-us.html` shows the title "Demo Title", description "Demo Description"
- `information.html` shows the title "Demo Title", description "Demo Description"

---

**I know I need to:**

- Add: 3 variables on the `contact-us.html` and `information.html` (but how?)

  - Var page-title = "Contact Us"
  - Var page-image = "/Contact-Us.png"
  - Var page-title = "Welcome to Contact Us"
- Update: `title-image-description.html`

  - Replace "Demo Title" with something like "<?php get-var:page-title>"
  - Replace "Demo Image" with something like "<?php get-var:page-image>"
  - Replace "Demo Description" with something like "<?php get-var:page-description>"

**QUESTIONS**

1. Should I use PHP or JS to create the variables.
2. What code should I use?

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve this problem using JavaScript. Im not sure if JavaScript is the best solution to this problem, but the below code works.

1. Update the template file

   **title-image-description.html**

   ```
   <div id="title"></div>
   <div id="image"></div>
   <div id="description"></div>
   ```
2. Update the the pages with this code.
   **contact-us.html & information.html**

   ```
   <div id="title-image-description.html"></div>

   <script>
   $(function(){
     $("##title-image-description").load("title-image-description.html", function() {
       $("#title").text('Contact Us');
       $("#image").text('/image.png');
       $("#description").text('Welcome to Contact Us');
     });
   });
   </script>
   ```